# A question about primary subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

I need the definition of Primary Subgroup, and some information about it.It was not found in any resource.Can you please advise me?
best regards.

Answer (score 1):

[It should be meant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) a subgroup, all of whose elements have period a power of a given prime $p$. (So a $p$-primary subgroup is one in which all elements have period a power of the prime $p$. And a primary subgroup is one that is $p$-primary for some prime $p$.)

In the finite case, we are talking groups of order a power of the prime $p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.So what is difference between p-groups and primary subgroups?

Comment: @asieh, seems to me they are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a billion needs here. :+)